# What does the word "typed" refer to in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, terminology

> C# 1.0 was released in 2002 and included all the important features of
> a statically **typed object oriented modern language**, as you will see
> throughout chapters 2 to 6.

This sentence has given from a programming language book.
So what does it mean by "typed"? Does it want to say: type of the language that we're talking about is  **object oriented**?
Can anyone explain this part to me?

Comment: This is a programming question. Find an answer at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages)

Comment: Agreed: this isn't about language. But here's a link that will explain what it means. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57471_01/bigData.100/extensions_bdd/src/cext_transform_typing.html#:~:text=First%2C%20dynamically%2Dtyped%20languages%20perform,type%20checking%20at%20compile%20time.&text=If%20a%20script%20written%20in,the%20errors%20have%20been%20fixed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a specialised IT meaning of a word.

Comment: I didn't ask about programming! I just asked about meaning of "typed" in such conditions. You may find some sentences like this from every books !

Comment: This is *not* a question about programming but about an English word **used in** programming which is perfectly fine on ELL.

Comment: But this meaning of **typed** is specific to programming.  I'm voting to close.

Comment: @Void I agree that questions about words used in specialized fields aren't always off-topic, but this is answerable with a dictionary: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/typed

Answer (score 2):

"typed" refers to variables types in a programming language.  The program needs to know what type - numeric, character, date, etc --  a variable is in order to interpret the underlying ones and zeroes.  For example, the character "A" and the integer 65 have the same underlying ones and zeroes. The program must know whether to use "A" or 65.  It gets much more complicated from there. "statically", for example, further refines "typed" and has a specific meaning within the realm of programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

"Typed" is only part of the adjective in this specific example..."statically typed" is a programming language characteristic (I would hyphenate this to "statically-typed" for clarity) and refers to variable types in computer languages, for example, an integer or a character.

Similarly, I would hyphenate "object-oriented" to avoid any similar confusion.